# How to add checkbox in ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have taken the below code from [How to create a checkbox using listview](https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-add-checkbox-in-listview-in-flutter/) which checks all the items when one item is checked. how do i fix the code to not to check all the items?

```
class CheckBoxInListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckBoxInListViewState createState() => _CheckBoxInListViewState();
}

class _CheckBoxInListViewState extends State<CheckBoxInListView> {
  bool _isChecked = false;

  List<String> _texts = [
    "InduceSmile.com",
    "Flutter.io",
    "google.com",
    "youtube.com",
    "yahoo.com",
    "gmail.com"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      children: _texts
          .map((text) => CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(text),
                value: _isChecked,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isChecked = val;
                  });
                },
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just make a List of '_isChecked' variable and use that.

```
class CheckBoxInListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckBoxInListViewState createState() => _CheckBoxInListViewState();
}

class _CheckBoxInListViewState extends State<CheckBoxInListView> {
  List<String> _texts = [
    "InduceSmile.com",
    "Flutter.io",
    "google.com",
    "youtube.com",
    "yahoo.com",
    "gmail.com"
  ];

  List<bool> _isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isChecked = List<bool>.filled(_texts.length, false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _texts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text(_texts[index]),
          value: _isChecked[index],
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(
              () {
                _isChecked[index] = val;
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked. could you please explain how the below code in the initState() works?
_isChecked = List<bool>.filled(_texts.length, false);

Comment: It creates a list of the given length(first parameter) and fill initial value(second parameter) all list. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/List/List.filled.html
 Initializing is required because of ' value: _isChecked[index],' part

Comment: Then how can we manage search in list because search list will be another list

Answer (score 2):

you should have a list for is checked, and assign them individually to each item.

```dart
class CheckBoxInListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckBoxInListViewState createState() => _CheckBoxInListViewState();
}

class _CheckBoxInListViewState extends State<CheckBoxInListView> {
  final List<SimpleModel> _items = <SimpleModel>[
    SimpleModel('InduceSmile.com', false),
    SimpleModel('Flutter.io', false),
    SimpleModel('google.com', false),
    SimpleModel('youtube.com', false),
    SimpleModel('yahoo.com', false),
    SimpleModel('gmail.com', false),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: _items
            .map(
              (SimpleModel item) => CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(item.title),
                value: item.isChecked,
                onChanged: (bool val) {
                  setState(() => item.isChecked = val);
                },
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      );
}

class SimpleModel {
  String title;
  bool isChecked;

  SimpleModel(this.title, this.isChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer with the most votes works with correction, reports two errors, errors and lines that have been corrected:

1. A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
   correction: _isChecked[index] = val!;
2. Non-nullable instance field '_isChecked' must be initialized.
   correction: **late** List _isChecked;